# Run expect inside a bash script as another user

Tags: bash, scripting, su, expect

I am writing a bash script to install some small software I'm developing. That script is run with `sudo` (as root), but some of the commands that are executed by the script need (or should be) run with a regular user whose name I keep in the `$userName` variable. Most of the commands are one liners and `su -c "/what/ever/command" $userName` works good enough.

However, one of those commands I don't want to run as `root` is going to ask me things (actually, only one thing, but many times: whether it should overwrite an existing file or not). That command which I may call "`baaad_command`" doesn't have any option to provide a default answer (there's no "`--assume-no`" or anything like that).

The only option I see feasible is using the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command, and reply "`n\r`" every time the command outputs and string witch starts with "`Overwrite`", I want my script to reply no (meaning "`n\r`") as many times as baaad_command asks `"Overwrite... ? [y/n]"`

I've tried many different combinations of su, spawn, expect... without any luck.

This is my last try so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -d "$destinationFolder" ]] ; then
    if [[ -n "$userName" ]] ; then
        spawned=$(su -c expect -c "
            spawn baaad_command --user \"foo\" --passwd \"bar\" \"$destinationFolder\"
             expect {
                 Overwrite: { send \"n\r\"; exp_continue }
                 eof { exit }
             }
        " )
    else
        echo "Don't have a non-root username to install baaad_command with. Skipping"
        exit 3
    fi
else
        echo "$destinationFolder directory not found in $(pwd). Can't continue"
        exit 2
fi
```

It doesn't have any remarkable thing over the other 200 tries... just happens to be the last.

Any hint will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try to send the answer via pipe. smth like `yes n|baaad_command` in some cases may work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to use `su -c 'expect -c "spawn ..."'` -- note the extra quotes.